# An old postal rebus

Tags: rebus

This was all that was written on the envelope:

[image]

Where should it be delivered?

*(Saw this somewhere ages ago. The original source has been lost to time.)*

Comment: This sounds like a letter that Willie Reginald Bray would send.

Comment: This is a nifty rebus and a cute puzzle. That said, were I the postal carrier, I'd still mark it as `UNDELIVERABLE` and return it to the sender.

Comment: The most cryptically addressed postcard I ever sent that I know to have been received was to: The Very Narrow House Opposite the Albion, Peel Terrace, STAFFORD. That was because I'd forgotten my friend's house number. One addressed to myself with just my house number and postcode never arrived.

Comment: I recently heard of a really *really* detailed address to the recipient that was delivered - the opposite of this problem, of course

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think it should be delivered to

> John Underwood

Who lives

> in [Andover, England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andover,_Hampshire)

As the rebus says

> John under Wood and over England

Comment: Can't believe I didn't get that, and my parents lived there for 20 years!

Comment: A follow up question. Is your dad's name John Underwood?

Answer (score 9):

Apparently that's a true story, about a real piece of mail.

You can stop wondering where you saw it before, here's a source:  :-)

> *The Telegraph:* [Baffling addresses that get delivered correctly](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/comment/letters/9347719/Baffling-addresses-that-get-delivered-correctly.html)

(Spoiler; the link also contains the answer.)